# Inverse Laplace Transform of $1/(s+a)$

Tags: indefinite-integrals, laplace-transform

Is the $a$ always a real value? So, if $a = 6$, then $\frac{1}{s+6}$ transforms to $e^{-6t}$. But can $a$ also take on complex values, such as $a = 4 + 5i$?

Comment: Well Kenny, why in the world would you imagine $a$ is real? It sounds to me as if you, and your fun-bots, need to sharpen your questions a tad :)

Comment: A.r.r. - Math Enjoyer helped me with understanding even more than what I asked. He taught me something very important today, and showed how to not just apply the Laplace transform associated with this case, but also analysis technique. And his teachings will go a long way, as I will pass on what he taught me. Also, thanks to Sammy for helping to format the symbols in my opening post.

Answer (score 4):

That's an interesting question. If you go to the Wikipedia article for the [Inverse Laplace Transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_Laplace_transform), you will find that the "Mellin's inverse formula" uses a limit involving complex numbers. Moreover, let us attempt to find the Laplace transform of $e^{-(a+bi)t}$ from the definition:
$$\mathscr{L}\left\{e^{-(a+bi)t}\right\}=\int_0^{\infty}e^{-(a+bi)t}e^{-st}dt=\int_0^{\infty}e^{-(s+a+bi)t}dt=-\bigg[\frac{1}{s+a+bi}e^{-(s+a+bi)t}\bigg]_0^{\infty}$$
Now the question becomes: What happens to this result as $t\to\infty$?
$$\lim_{t\to\infty}e^{-(s+a+bi)t}=\lim_{t\to\infty}e^{-st}\cdot e^{-at}\cdot e^{-bti}=^{?}\lim_{t\to\infty}e^{-st}\cdot \lim_{t\to\infty}e^{-at}\cdot \lim_{t\to\infty}e^{-bti}.$$
For the integral to be convergent, this upper limit should also converge. Hence, we would need the equality marked with a question mark to hold, and for each limit to be non-infinite. Notice that the first limit is zero, because $s>0$. As for the second limit, this is the one that could give us problems, as $e^{-at}$ will explode at $t\to\infty$ if $a<0$. The last limit requires us to notice that $e^{tbi}=\cos(tb)+i\sin(tb)$, which doesn't converge when $t\to\infty$, but it remains bounded by the disk $|z|\leq1$ (so this one doesn't give any restrictions). Hence, the Laplace transform of $e^{-(a+bi)t}$ will only exist if $a\geq 0$. In the end, we got the upper limit $t\to\infty$ to vanish, so we are only left with the lower limit $t=0$, and then:
$$\mathscr{L}\left\{e^{-(a+bi)t}\right\}=\frac{1}{s+(a+bi)}.$$
Thus, the inverse Laplace transform $\mathscr{L}^{-1}\left\{\frac{1}{s+(a+bi)}\right\}$ only exists if $a\geq 0$, and it is $e^{-(a+bi)t}$. So yes, we can extend the inverse Laplace transform of $\frac{1}{s+z}$ to the complex numbers, but only those with non-negative real part, and the result will also be the corresponding exponential.

Edit: I changed some negative/positive signs to be consistent with the original question.

Comment: Thanks very much Math Enjoyer. The question was asked because the examples I saw were all with real values. This helps tremendously. Thanks again!